# Combining and rearranging two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having two dataframes with each of them looking like

```
date       country      value
20100101   country1       1
20100102   country1       2
20100103   country1       3


date       country      value
20100101   country2       4
20100102   country2       5
20100103   country2       6
```

I want to merge them into one dataframe looking like

```
date       country1     country2
20100101       1           4
20100102       2           5
20100103       3           6
```

Is there any clever way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like pivot table, which in Pandas is called `unstack` for some bizarre reason.

Example analogous to the one used in Wes McKinley's "python for data analysis" book:

```
bytz = df.groupby(['tz', opersystem])
counts = bytz.size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

(`groupby` operating system in rows which is then pivoted so that operating system becomes columns, just like your "country*" values).

P.S. for `cat`ting dataframes you can use `pandas.concat`. It's also often good to do `.reset_index` on resulting dataframe, bc in some (many?) cases duplicate values in index can make pandas go haywire, throwing strange exceptions on `.apply` used on dataframe and the like.

Comment: ?  The method to produce a pivot table isn't called `unstack`, it's called `pivot_table`.